# Regexps in Elisp to include newlines

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp

I'm trying to add a special markup to Python documentation strings in emacs (python-mode).

Currently I'm able to extract a single line with:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords
 'python-mode
 '(("\\(\"\\{3\\}\\.+\"\\{3\\}\\)"
    1 font-lock-doc-face prepend)))
```

This works now:

```
"""Foo"""
```

But as soon there is a newline like:

```
"""
Foo

"""
```

It doesn't work anymore. This is logical, since `.` doesn't include newlines (`\n`).
Should I use a character class?

How can I correct this regular expression to include everything between `""" """`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

```
"\\(\"\\{3\\}\\(.*\n?\\)*?\"\\{3\\}\\)"
```

The "*?" construct is the non-greedy version of "*".

Comment: For some strange reason my emacs hangs when using this regexp.

Hangs at `Loading vc...done`

Answer (score 0):

A newline in emacs regexps is entered by C-q C-j so just stick a group containing . and C-q C-j into your regexp. As I use regexp-tool to build them, mine isn't fully quoted as yours, but I hope the changes are obvious.

`\("\{3\}\(.\|`C-qC-j`\)+"\{3\}\)`

Sorry I can't format it better, stackoverflow doesn't agree with me.

Also it will probably display as a newline in emacs.

Comment: This isn't correct.  For string literals in elisp, you do use `\n`. When entering a regex interactivity, such as with a regex isearch, only then will `\n` not be a newline, and `C-q C-j` is needed instead.

Answer (score 0):

This works half:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords
     'python-mode
      '(("\\(\"\\{3\\}\\(.\\|\n\\)*?\"\\{3\\}\\)" 
         1 font-lock-warning-face prepend)))
```

But when adding RET's the markup is gone.

The suggested regexp `"\\(\"\\{3\\}\\(.*\n?\\)*?\"\\{3\\}\\)"` makes my emacs hang when opening a .py file.

Maybe it's time to visit the emacs mailinglist..

Comment: @JoelBorggrén-Franck is wrong, `\n` in a Lisp string represents a newline.

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest way is this one:

```
font-lock-add-keywords
 'python-mode
 '(("\\(\"\\{3\\}\\[^|]*?\"\\{3\\}\\)"
    1 font-lock-doc-face prepend)))
```

You can use any character that is definitly not between """ and """ instead of *|*.

Comment: But there is no guarantee that the string doesn't contain every possible ASCII character. That's why the delimiter consists of three identical characters. I suppose you could work around it with something like `\\([^\"]+\\(\"[^\"]\\|\"\"[^\"]\\)\\?\\)*`